# Bootstrap Modal is Closing Autonomously

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap Modal (**BS 4**) that almost works perfectly, except that it closes itself after 1-2 seconds.  It's not supposed to close itself and I cannot see any reason for it to do so.  I see nothing in my code that would cause it to close and I see no errors reported using Dev Tools with Chrome or Firefox.  Quite frankly, I'm stumped on how to troubleshoot.

This is an intranet site where we record information about applications our division supports.  This includes a page for listing all apps and on that page is a button for adding information about a new application.  This calls a Bootstrap modal, which works great.  User information is accepted and saved to the database.  Upon saving, this modal is closed (desired result) and a second modal is opened.  This second one notifies the user that the save was successful and asks them if they'd like to open the details page for this new app or return to the app list page and has two buttons (Yes: opens details page; No: returns to list page).  If you hit either of the buttons quick enough (roughly one second), they will take you to the correct page.  If you pick neither button, then it will take you to the app list page after about 1.5 seconds <- this auto closure is not desired and what I'm trying to troubleshoot.

In both browsers (Chrome/FF), if I hit the stop button on the browser just after this second modal opens, I can see the application list page is already queued up (viewing Dev Tools).  I see nothing in my code to automatically call the page reload.  I just want the second dialog to remain active/visible until the user takes action.

Seems like time for some code....

```
if (save_ready) {
    $.when(insertApp()).done(function () {
        //this code is executed when all ajax calls are done
        $("#ucAppInsert").modal('hide');
        openConfirmation();
    });
}
```

Quick explanation: save_ready is true when all required fields have data.  Simple boolean and it works.  insertApp() is the function that activates the ucAppInsert modal, which contains the data elements for adding the new record.  This function includes the AJAX calls to the database for inserting the new record and receiving the new record's ID value or any error messages from the DB.  As you can see, when that's done, the code then hides the modal and executes openConfirmation().  Up to this point, all works perfectly as far as I can tell.

```
function openConfirmation() {
    // called by the applicable control, this opens the confirmation dialog so user
    // can either open the compliance details page for adding VRM, etc or dismissing
    $("#confirmationModal").modal();
}
```

So, here we are, opening the Confirmation Modal.  Simple enough.

And now, the modal itself:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title" id="ConfirmationModalLabel">New Application Added</div>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <span id="AppInsertResultMsg"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span id="app_insert_good_mdlbtn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn button button-links-alt" onclick="window.location.reload();">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn button button-links" onclick="openDetailsForNewApp();">Yes</button>
                </span>

                <span id="app_insert_err_mdlbtn">                   
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.reload();">OK</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a simple modal.  I have a span in the middle where I drop the applicable message: which would be text with the new app's ID or an error message.

In the footer, I have two spans.  The first is only visible when there were no errors detected in the save operation, the second is only visible when there were errors detected in the save operation.

Again, everything works perfectly, except that the modal closes autonomously.

I do not see anything in the code path above that would cause it to close.  There are no known errors - none reported by the browsers and none reported by the database.  I have compared this modal with other modals and I don't see anything different in how they're being called or formatted.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this one?

Comment: maybe intercept the modal close events and do not open the second modal until the first modal complete? Maybe? just a guess that they might be stepping on one another.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting.  That was my thought too.

However, I'm explicitly closing my first modal before calling the function that ultimately opens the second modal.  In each case, I'm explicitly opening/closing modals via their ID, which "should" avoid the wrong object being acted upon.



`$("#ucAppInsert").modal('hide');

openConfirmation();`



I believe there's a method for detecting when the first modal is closed.  Maybe I'll use that to trigger the openConfirmation function.  That would(?) for sure prevent the close collision.  Maybe.

Comment: Maybe intercept the close event and take a look at the call stack?

Comment: And as suspected, I'm a dummy.

I completely overlooked that I had added a couple of lines of code that forces refresh when modals are hidden.  In my defense, it's been well over a year since I added that.

At least now I know root cause.  I'll just grab my coloring book and go back in the corner.

Thanks @fnostro for your suggestions.

Comment: Been there.  Hope my suggestions helped. Happy Coding :)